# Ruby on Rails/How to Scaffold form link to specific action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

My scaffold model doesn't work well with `create` action.
I found out that if I press submit button, it is linked to `TalksController#index` but it should be linked to `TalksController#create`

I don't know how I can fix it to link to create action. There aren't any codes related to it in `_form.html.erb` and new.html.erb

`Create` worked well 2 days ago.

[edit]I post my codes.
I added some codes in addition to the codes scaffold made itself

talks_controller.rb

```
  class TalksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_talk, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [ :index, :show, :all ]

  # GET /talks
  # GET /talks.json

  def all
    @talks = Talk.all
    @talks = Talk.order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def index
    @talks = Talk.all
    @talks = Talk.order(created_at: :desc)

    @whichboard = params[:whichboard]
    @seq = params[:saveit]
    @title = params[:savetitle]
  end

  # GET /talks/1
  # GET /talks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /talks/new
  def new
    @talk = Talk.new
    @seq = params[:seq]
    @whichboard = params[:whichboard]
  end

  # GET /talks/1/edit
  def edit
    authorize_action_for @talk
  end

  # POST /talks
  # POST /talks.json
  def create
    @talk = Talk.new(talk_params)
    @talk.user_id = current_user
    @talk.seq = params[:talk][:seq]
    @talk.where = params[:talk][:where]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @talk.save
        format.html { redirect_to @talk, notice: 'Talk was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @talk }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @talk.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /talks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /talks/1.json
  def update
    authorize_action_for @talk
    respond_to do |format|
      if @talk.update(talk_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @talk, notice: 'Talk was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @talk }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @talk.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end


  # DELETE /talks/1
  # DELETE /talks/1.json
  def destroy
    authorize_action_for @talk
    @talk.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to talks_url, notice: 'Talk was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_talk
      @talk = Talk.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def talk_params
      params.require(:talk).permit(:content, :user_id, :seq, :where)
    end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@talk) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :content %>
    <%#= f.association :user %>
    <%= f.input :seq,  :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => @seq } %>
    <%= f.input :where,  :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => @whichboard } %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class='col-md-12'>
    <p style='text-align:right;'>
      created by <%= current_user.name %>, Current Time : <%= Time.now %>, board <%= @whichboard %> seq <%= @seq %>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', talks_path %>
```

[SECOND EDIT] routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  root 'cpu#index'
  post ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'


  resources :talks
end
```

Comment: can you post the form and controller for us please

Comment: I'm sorry it is the first time I write a question myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adjust your routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  root 'cpu#index'


  resources :talks

  #do you really need these? 
  post ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'



end
```

to put the `resources :talks` above the default/catchall routes. the routes are processed on first match, so if you need those default/catchalls youcan put them at the bottom. That being said, unless you have a requirement for them most modern rails apps don't require them by default, so you can probably comment out / remove them as another option.

Comment: solved! I can't thank you enough to everyone who wrote answer to my question. Thank you thousands!

Answer (score 0):

The index and create both refer to the same url or the same route method, the only difference is the method if you use the method as post then, it'll go to create otherwise it goes to index. But, you could implicitly handle this if you pass in the new instance of the object you are trying to create such as @customer = Customer.new then, pass @customer to the form_for method.

Comment: I used the method as post, but it goes to index although it should go to create..

Comment: Can you post your code for the view, controller and routes.rb configuration

Comment: I already posted 'new' view and controller. I'll post routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

With the form_for method, you can specify url of the action you want to be executed or just controller and action like this:

```
<%= form_for @post, :url => {:controller => "your-controller-name", :action => "your-action-name"} do |f| %>
```

And in your action ("your-action-name") you can call your parameters like:

```
post_id = params[:post][:id]
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: I referred your advice. I adapted little bit because my code use simple_form_for. I fixed to "<%= simple_form_for @talk, url: '/talks/create' do |f|%>" it links to /talks/create and work well, but I get "The action '11' could not be found for TalksController" error. ('11' means the id of newly added data)

Comment: Ok, so you just have to add the action path to your routes.rb file in /config, and that's will be ok, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more infos.